Is it safe to totally unregister the default "post" Post Type
I would like to start a fresh WordPress install and unregister the default "post" Post Type (and by unregister it, I mean totally wipe it out (database included)).
Is it a safe purpose ? And will the updates be okay ?

There is a WP function unregister_post_type() but it can't be used to unregister built-in post types.  The Post type is fundamental to WordPress' function.  If you remove the posts table from the database then things will likely fail very quickly and very badly.  What benefit would you hope to gain by doing this?

I know this function. The thing is : I plan to create a large amount of custom post type, lets say, more than 20, with custom taxonomies. I will use the "page" post type but I won't use the default "post" post type, so I wanted to remove it to clean the database and the dashboard to increase performances.

There's no benefit to unregistering the post post type. If you never add a post to your site, no room will be taken up in the DB by posts. All post types, built-in and otherwise, use the wp_posts table as storage, so removing that table would be catastrophic.

You cannot achieve a performance benefit (or any other benefit) by attempting to remove the post type.  If you are experiencing a performance problem then find the real root of the problem and address that.  If you don't create any posts then there's nothing in the database to clean.  If you want to remove "Posts" from the admin user interface then you can create a new user role and give it no capabilities for posts.
